# What is Odin's present age?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The sum of the ages of Odin and Tom is $40$. In $5$ years, $5$ more than $2$ times of Tom's age will be equal to $3$ times of Odin's age. What is Odin's present age?

---

I'm having trouble with this question, even thought It seems easy.

> The sum of the ages of Odin and Tom is $40$.

$$ O + T = 40$$

> $5$ more than $2$ times of Tom's age will be equal to $3$ times of Odin's age

$$3(O)+5 = 2(O+5)+5 $$

However, the second equation seems truly wrong.

Comment: when you say '2 times of three times' do you essentially mean 6 times?

Comment: In five years Tom's age will be $T+5$ and it will be $5+2(3(O+5))$ ?

Comment: @Rishi No, I didn't mean that.

Comment: See the new edit, corrected my grammar mistake.

Comment: In $5$ years, $5$ more than $2$ times of Tom's age will be equal to $3$ times of Odin's age

Comment: $5+2(T+5)=3(O+5)$ that means : $2T=3O$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the following  equations,

Let $O $ be odins present age and $T$
 be Toms  present age

$O+T =40\implies T = 40-O$

and

$2(T +5 )+5 = 3(O+5)$

$2(40-O)+10+5 = 3O +15 $

$ 80 -2O +15 = 3O +15$

$5O = 80$

$O = 16$

Answer (score 2):

Suppose Odin= O and Tom= T

From the first equation we got

$O+T= 40$

And for the second we got

$5+2(T+5) = 3(O+5)$

And we simplify to get

$2T = 3O$ or $ T= 1.5O$

Substitute to the first equation,  we got

$1.5O + O = 40$

$2.5O = 40$

O= 16

So,  Odin,'s present age is 16 years old.

Hopes it helps.

Answer (score 2):

5 more than 2 times of Tom's age will be equal to 3 times of Odin's age

5  more than (2 times of Tom's age) will be equal to (3 times of Odin's age)

(2 times of Tom's age)+5 = (3 times of Odin's age)

$$2T+5 = 3O$$

---

In 5 years, 5 more than 2 times of Tom's age will be equal to 3 times of Odin's age

$$2(T+5)+5 = 3(O+5)$$